# how to retrive facebook photos from test user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i created facebook app that can get user photos to my website

i created app and set website and checked permission for user_photos

and i used test user that created in roles left pane at test users tab

and i login with this user and uploaded photos and set it public

and get my app access token

but when i send request as follows:

https://graph.facebook.com/TestUserID/photos?access_token=#########|#########

the response is :
 "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
 "type": "OAuthException",
 "code": 102

so how i can solve the problem?

Comment: Get a user access token, by sending the test user through the login flow. (And please try and make _some_ use of punctuation in the future, if possible. Endless sentences without period or comma are hard to read …)

Comment: you mean i won't use app access token?but i will use user access token

Comment: _“A __user__ access token is required”_ – it doesn’t get any clearer than this.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the App Access token for the request.

To fetch user's private data (e.g. user's images), you must implement a [Facebook Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web).

This means, that the user will need to:

1. Log in with Facebook to your application
2. Grant your app the permissions to access the photos

After your user has logged in, you will get a **User Access Token** that you can use to make requests to Facebook's API on behalf of the user.

Check the link above for further instructions for obtaining the access token.

The simplest code to perform the login (on the frontend) would be:

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
  });

  FB.login(function(response) {
      console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken); // This will output the user access token
  }, {scope: 'public_profile, user_photos'});
}
```

Remember to include the Facebook JS SDK to your page.

Comment: when i log with test user and get access token i tried use Graph API Explorer and select photos the response is empty while the test user generated i set some photos for him

Comment: @user5740661 can you check with [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) that your access token has `user_photos` listed in the `Scopes` section?